# C++ Sqlite3 print a row

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite, c++17

```
void Database::searchBook (const std::string& name) {
    sqlite3_open ("books.db", &db);
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2 (db, "SELECT * WHERE Name = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg (db) << std::endl;
    }
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, name.c_str (), name.length (), NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << sqlite3_errmsg (db) << std::endl;
    }
    sqlite3_step (stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize (stmt);
    sqlite3_close (db);
}
```

I have selected the row, where the name is similar to the input, put how can I manage to print it out in the console? Do I need to store it in a vector or so?

Comment: Yes, you should find instructions in sqlite's documentation how to retrieve the SELECTed rows into variables. Once you have them, you can do whatever you want with them, print them on the console, etc...

Comment: So there is no other way than an external variable?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`sqlite3_column_text` et al](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)

Comment: Correct. There does not appear to be any function in the sqlite library that automatically shows the results of a query on standard output.